# How to git pull from github and push to heroku?

Tags: github, heroku

I already have a repo deployed on heroku.
And I develop it by github.

Now I don't have a local repo of my project. (Since AWS doesn't work)
And the version of github is faster than heroku.

I want to deploy the newest github version on heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First login heroku

```
heroku login
```

clone from the heroku app

```
heroku git:clone -a heroku-app-name
cd heroku-app-name
```

check remote heroku

```
git remote -v
```

you should see

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/heroku-app-name.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/heroku-app-name.git (push)
```

add remote origin

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:yourname/reponame.git
git remote -v
```

you should see

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/heroku-app-name.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/heroku-app-name.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:yourname/reponame.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:yourname/reponame.git (push)
```

fetch remote origin and update remote heroku

```
git pull origin master
git push heroku master
```